# .ipa file install grayed out on an ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios7, ipa

One of my tester is having an issue with installing an ad-hoc distribution build of an ipa file on an ipad.  He said that icon stays gray and also his iTune freezes.  When clicked, it just sits there as waiting.

The UDID he gave me was the one that he got from iTunes (not the app that gives invalid ffff udid), and I double checked it through checkipa (https://github.com/apperian/iOS-checkIPA) and indeed his UDID is included.  Just to make sure I even built him a new build but with no luck.  Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may have an issue with your bundle id, as suggested.

Otherwise I would suggest forgoing the use of iTunes, and use a distribution service such as [TestFlight](http://www.testflightapp.com/) or [HockyApp](http://hockeyapp.net), because iTunes is a pain to use for distributing builds and it wouldn't surprise me if a user is having problems trying to get iTunes to cooperate.

This won't solve any issues with your provisioning, but over the air distribution is a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to an issue with the bundle id. Double check that the id you packaged your app with is *exactly* the same as that in the provisioning profile.

I once had a very similar problem simply because one was referencing "...ar" and the other was referencing "...AR" - so be very sure they are both exactly the same!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in distribution build using enterprise certificates and many suggests you to revoke new certificates with new prov file. But it may stop your previous working apps built on the existing certificates if you revoke. Instead try to add Apple's WWDRCA certificate available in apple certificate forums in your keychain as it completely authenticates your ipa file while installing on ipads.